# Strange problem when Comparing NSDate values and EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, exc-bad-access

i'm working on a program that compares date values and sets the beggining date if the newly selected date is smaller than the dateStart and sets the dateEnd if the newly selected date is bigger than dateStart.

The code works well when i choose bigger values (while setting dateEnd) but program crashed when i try to set dateStart. heres my code:

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)dateVal
{
    NSComparisonResult result = [dateVal compare:dateStart];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy 00:00:00"];

    switch (result)
    {
        case NSOrderedAscending: 
        {
            dateStart = dateVal;
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy 00:00:00"];
            [lblDateStart setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateStart]];
        } break;
        case NSOrderedDescending:{ 
            dateEnd = dateVal;
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy 23:59:59"];
            [lblDateEnd setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateEnd]];
        } break;
        case NSOrderedSame: NSLog(@"%@ is the same as %@", dateStart, dateVal); break;
        default: NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", dateStart, dateVal); break;
    }
}
```

The code gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at

> NSComparisonResult result = [dateVal
>   compare:dateStart];

when i select a smaller date value from the calendar view.

i've both set dateStart and dateEnd as property and [[NSDate alloc] init] for both of them at the beginning. please help.

Comment: Two things. Have you tried using Zombies to debug the code, and is it possible that dateVal might be a pointer to something you released earlier?

Comment: Nicholas, i've fixed the problem by changing dateStart = dateVal to [self setdateStart:dateVal] i realized that it was not a proper way to assign date. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys i've finally realized the problem.

The problem was in this line:

```
dateStart = dateVal;
```

but it has to be like this:

```
[self setdateStart:dateVal];
```

Thanks and have a nice day.